# Macros which hides the rows through the cell activation

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following task: I want to write a macro that can be activated when you click on a specific cell and hides a certain number of rows under it.

I suppose that I need to solve the following problems:

1. I need to call macros when I select the cell.
2. We need to detect the exact coordinates of selected cell.
3. The final point: we need to hide N rows under the selected cell.

The first point works good because I found the code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox 'you clicked d4!'
        End If
    End If
'End Sub
```

But when I try to replace the `MsgBox 'you clicked d4!'`for:

```
callingCellRow = Application.Caller.Row
```

It does not work Error:

> the variable is undefined

Can you give some examples or provide the code which combines these thirds points?

Comment: `Application.Caller.Row` -----> `Target.Row`.

Comment: Also it is safer to replace `Selection.Count` with `Target.CountLarge`.

Comment: when using `Option Explicit` one must declare all variables before assigning them values.  So add `Dim callingCellRow As Long` at the top of the sub.  Then use  `callingCellRow = Target.Row`